# React Native Jest : Test is not defined (Testing)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to run the most basic example with Jest, yet I don't seem to be able to. Followed the instructions here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html

Here is my code:

```
import Actions, {
  reducer,
  INITIAL_STATE,
} from "../../App/Redux/AcModelDeleteRedux";

test("request", () => {
  const data = [];
  const state = reducer(INITIAL_STATE, Actions.acModelDeleteRequest(data));
  expect(state.fetching).toBe(true);
  expect(state.data).toStrictEqual(data);
  expect(state.error).toBeNull();
});

test("success", () => {
  const payload = [];
  const state = reducer(INITIAL_STATE, Actions.acModelDeleteSuccess(payload));
  expect(state.fetching).toBe(false);
  expect(state.payload).toStrictEqual(payload);
  expect(state.error).toBeNull();
});

test("failure", () => {
  const state = reducer(INITIAL_STATE, Actions.acModelDeleteFailure());
  expect(state.fetching).toBe(false);
  expect(state.error).toStrictEqual(true);
  expect(state.payload).toBeNull();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a jest config file?

Comment: @TaghiKhavari I have

Answer (score 0):

Node and jest version mismatch could cause the error.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9538

Comment: @DishantChanchad, please post your `package.json` content.

Answer (score -1):

In Jest tests, the file extension must be .test.js . You need to change the file extension to `.test.js`

Comment: And make sure you have “type” as module in your package.json

Comment: not working please explain me more details

Comment: Umm, I can help better if you can post your package.json in your question. You can remove the name if you're not comfortable with it.

Comment: And also your directory structure